# How to open a Submenu clicking on an Anchor Link?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, bootstrap-4, wordpress-theming

I have this bootstrap-accordion code inside a Wordpress Theme:

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu-horizontal-1" class="mobile-menu accordion-menu">
    <li id="accordion-menu-item-1906" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children has-sub">
    <a class="nolink" href="#">CLICK ME</a><span class="arrow"></span>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="accordion-menu-item-1922" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="/one" class="">ONE</a></li>
        <li id="accordion-menu-item-1904" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="/two" class="">TWO</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

When i click on the ARROW, the submenu opens and closes correctly, collapsing and expanding and so on.

**Now, i want to make it happen the same thing, when i click on the anchor link "CLICK ME". I want the submenu to open and close like when i click on the arrow.**

Which data-attributes / class, must I attach to that link to 'activate' it and command the sub-menu ?

Please help, i'm stuck with it.

Comment: adding class `arrow` to the anchor tag **may** solve the issue.  
add you javascript codes for further help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below jQuery code to toggle the menu on click of **click me.**

```
$('.nolink').click(function() {
    $('.sub-menu').toggle();
});
```